# How to fix Order matching query doesn't exist in Django?

Tags: python, django

Unable to delete an object:
HViews is as follows

```
def deleteorder(request, pk):
     order = Order.object.get(id=pk)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         order.delete()
         return redirect()
    context = {'item':order}
return render(request,'accounts/delet.html', context)
```

And

Urls.py is as

```
path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteorder, name= 'delete_order')
```

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model): 
    STATUS = ( (' Pending', 'Pending'), ('Out for Delivery ', 'Out for Delivery '), ('Delivered ', 'Delivered ') , ) 
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL) 
    products = models.ForeignKey( Product, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL) 
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices = STATUS) 
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.products.name
```

Comment: You need to modify your url, path('delete_order/<int:pk>/', views.deleteorder, name= 'delete_order') and pass the pk with the url. Using DeleteView is the best practice in such cases.     https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview

Comment: I did it so but same result.

Comment: are you sending the pk parameter? are you able to print the pk in views?

Comment: Yes I have placed  pk as a parameter in deleteorder views but can't delete the already placed orders.

Comment: This is happening because there is no object with pk you are passing. You need to recheck whether you are passing the right pk. Your code is breaking when you are looking fir order with pk=id. Can you share Order model and few database records screenshot

Comment: class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for Delivery', 'Out for Delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            )
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.products.name

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your Order Model, the only thing that remains now is, you are passing wrong pk, for which no record is present

Comment: so where I have to pass pk in my code?

Comment: Share your template which makes the POST call. (add your template code in your question)

Comment: Posted in new answer. please visit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see it it work for you. How to delete an order by ID or pk. For example you have order views like this:

```
def order_views(request):
    my_order = OrderItem.objects.all()
    #you can also filter through your order
    context = {'my_order': my_order} 

 {% for order in my_order %}
#Your code here
<a href="{url 'deleteorder' order.pk }">Delete</a>
 {% endfor %}

def deleteorder(request, pk):
     order = Order.object.get(id=pk)
     order.delete()
     return redirect()

path('delete_order/<pk>/', views.deleteorder, name= 'delete_order') 
or 
path('delete_order/<int:pk>/', views.deleteorder, name= 'delete_order')
```

Remember to pass the correct Order context with the pk in template, so you don't get reverse not found.

Comment: I did so but same result is produced. What to do so?

Comment: I did same but same result is produced

Comment: @Muhammad.. Post your Order Model. The query doesn't exist in Django because there is an error in your code, it seems you are not getting the actual pk. Maybe you can change pk to id in your url and views. Try to print out the ID and let me know what you got.

Comment: @Muhammad... Try Order = objects.filter(id=pk)

Comment: I tried order=Order.objects.filter(id=pk)But I got an error which is telling me that Reverse for 'delete_order' with arguments '(",)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_order/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: Order model is given below:    class Order(models.Model):      STATUS = (    (' Pending', 'Pending'),      ('Out for Delivery ', 'Out for Delivery '), ('Delivered ', 'Delivered ') , )        customers = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)     products = models.ForeignKey( Product, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)   creared_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)  status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices = STATUS) def __str__(self):  return self.products.name

Comment: @Muhammad.. Update your question with Model.py,forms.py, views.py and template. You have reverse not found because you are not passing the right context of Order to its pk. Try adding the context in url template. Example.. {% url 'delete_order' item.pk %} or   {% url 'deleteorder' item.pk %} if you have a namespace you can also pass it in the url. Like;  {% url 'your_namespace:delete_order' item.pk %}. Let me know what you got.

Comment: bro it is still not working and I am getting confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: btw thank you so much and I think I can't solve the problem.

Comment: @Muhammad.. There is a way to do this with just url, just that your question lacks more information. I just updated my answer, using the url to delete the order by pk. You can also change pk to id, so you can print out the ID and see if it prints out the ID of the order you are trying to delete. And also try to post your Order views.py, you don't need to pass context in delete views. Try it and let me know what you got.

Comment: @Muhammad.. I have made an example in my answer, I hope you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

my code where POST is being called is given below.

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}

        {{form}}

    <hr>

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Man!!! you need to show all the related code, you are doing it wrong. Share Forms and GET function for this template

Comment: And this code is supposed to be in the Question itself not in the answer